# Force datetime returned by server

Tags: php, date

For a test suite of application, i need to force a date. These tests need to be runned in specific period (a date between 01-01-2012 and 31-12-2012). I can't modify the thousand files of application without modify stability of code, i need a way to specify it in bootstrap or something like replace the date returned by server.
Is it possible? If yes, how?

**Edit**: With comments: How overload functions date, datetime, etc ?

Comment: `echo time()` -> `echo 12345678` ... ?

Comment: I think you need to elaborate a bit on this to make it an actual question. Do you mean how to mock time? But then which time exactly?

Comment: I can't modify the thousand files of application without modify stability of code, i need a way to specify it in bootstrap or somthing like that.

Comment: So you want to "fake" the date so that `time()`, for example, returns a hard-coded date?

Comment: Yes: fake 'date()', 'datetime()' function will work i think. How replace/overload these functions ?

Comment: It could be work: http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.override-function.php#50821

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is to to first refactor all uses of time() and date() to something like gettime() and getdate() and then override those functions in the test suite.  This is how testable code is structured (or better yet, pass in the time to all functions that need it).

Alternatively, you  could run the tests in an environment where they can safely set the system time.

Finally, you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-redefine.php to override the function if you enable runkit.internal_override